# Use Django with Python3?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've been following the official Django tutorial, but I cannot get it to work with Python 3.
I used:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

in order to create a site, but it runs on Python2... Since I know all the syntax for Python3 I would really like to find a way to code in Python3

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You should try: python3 -m django-admin startproject name_of_project.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. As Ribodou said, the following command was the key:

```
python3 -m django-admin startproject name_of_project
```

But..! I got an error, saying that couldn't find django admin.
So, it worked with the following command:

```
python3 -m django startproject name_of_project
```

Hope it helps someone else !